# Angular.js 6.1.0 - Variable not being passed to the view

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-framework

I'm revising my angular by working through a tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4JUm0Bq9AM

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/154/Angular-6-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-6-in-this-Crash-Course

I have these two files for my sidebar:

sidebar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((_: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = _.url);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

sidebar.component.ts

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="" [class.activated]="currentUrl == '/'">
        <i class="material-icons">supervised_user_circle</i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="posts" [class.activated]="currentUrl == '/posts'">
        <i class="material-icons">message</i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is that `currentUrl` is not being passed to the view. I've checked and double checked that my code is exactly what is shown in the video and have pasted directly from the text version of the tut, but to no avail.

I've confirmed that 1, it is being set (via a `console.log`) and 2, that is is not being passed to the view (via dumping the variable to the page using `{{ currentUrl }}`).

If anyone could point me to where the problem lies I'd be v grateful.

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue? In the code you've provided there's no reason for it not to display if you were to use `{{currentUrl}}` in the template

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/tombusby/angular.js-revision

Comment: When I log the events, the latest one is always undefined

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that too, I tried only setting it if `_.url` is truthy, but it's still not passed to the view.

Comment: I've also tried disabling `router.events.subscribe((_: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = _.url);` and directly setting the variable, still empty in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the original code, even though you've typed the event as `NavigationEnd`, not all of the events actually are `NavigationEnd` events, and therefore they don't all have the `url` property.

We can add the `.filter` operator here to filter out any events that aren't `NavigationEnd` events. That way, they should all have a `url` property so that `currentUrl` doesn't get overwritten to `undefined`

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter((evt) => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((_: NavigationEnd) => {
      this.currentUrl = _.url;
    });
```

**[Here is a fork of the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-fn1g2a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidebar%2Fsidebar.component.scss)**

Comment: ERROR ReferenceError: filter is not defined

Comment: You'll need the import: `import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';` (which is assuming you're using rxjs 6 as in the StackBlitz)

Comment: Yeah I just spotted that in the stackblitz. That does appear to work.

Could you add a quick explainer why it didn't work before (and also why disabling the dynamic stuff and directly setting currentUrl to '/' failed).

Comment: I've added an explainer, but what do you mean by `disabling the dynamic stuff and directly setting currentUrl to '/' failed`? Can you reproduce that behaviour?

Comment: empty constructor and `currentUrl: string = '/';` (setting it within `constructor()` does seem to work though).

Comment: I can't reproduce that, seems to work when I try it?

Comment: Lol, neither can I now. Ok, thanks v much for your help, really appreciated.